# Can't analyse PE files more than certain size

Tags: c++, portable-executable, entropy

Currently, my code is able to get the entropy and file offset of PE files that are less than 3MB, tested with notepad.exe. However, I receive errors whenever I try to analyse a bigger file instead.

I am not sure how I should solve this problem. But my lecturer told me to create another similar function. Really appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Error shown in CLI:

```
Call to ReadFile() failed.
Error Code: 998
```

Error portion:

```
dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
if (dwFileSize != INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
{
    bFile = (byte*)malloc(dwFileSize);
```

Comment: The code is leaking the returned byte*.  This does not go on forever, eventually malloc() returns NULL to indicate that it can't allocate more memory.  Which you don't check so inevitably ReadFile() will keel over.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Consider the obvious solutions.  Like calling free().  And targeting x64.

Comment: much better idea: forget that `malloc` and `free` exist, use `std::make_unique<char[]>`, and let the library take care of the allocation and deallocation details.

Comment: I have added in the free(bFile) under my main function. But I am not sure how should I edit my pointer code to ensure that memory is not leaked.

Comment: It works now, but it takes a few seconds longer when analyzing bigger files. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're error code decodes to "Invalid access to memory location" and you're not checking the return value of malloc, and even if you were you need to loop on ReadFile to read the whole thing in.

You ran out of memory. You certainly need to redesign your algorithm.

And as Hans Passant pointed out, you have a memory leak because you never free the file's memory when you are done with it. C++ isn't garbage collected.

Comment: C++ isn't garbage collected, but it does have smart pointer and container classes that do automatic memory management.

Comment: I have added in the free(bFile) under my main function. But I am not sure how should I edit my pointer code to ensure that memory is not leaked.

Comment: It works now, but it takes a few seconds longer when analyzing bigger files. Thanks anyways :)